# how to use python variables in bash script inside python script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, curl, subprocess

I am trying to use my python variables inside the bash script in the python script as below...

```
import os
import submodule
URL="http://wmqa.blob.core.windows.net..."
os.system(subprocess.call("curl -I --silent GET ",str(URL), "| awk '/x-ms-copy-status/ {print}'"))

# I also tried with 

os.system(subprocess.call("curl -I --silent GET "+URL+ "| awk '/x-ms-copy-status/ {print}'"))
```

how can I able to pass the URL after `GET` in curl  also I need to execute some extra commands after the curl to fetch the status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, it is probably best not to use `os.system`. It was replaced a long time ago (19 years ago, actually; in [PEP 324](https://peps.python.org/pep-0324/)). To answer your question, you can reference a variable using f-strings, or any other formatting allowed in strings in python. Here is an example.

```py
import subprocess

my_var = "hello from my shell"
subprocess.Popen(f"echo {my_var}", shell=True).wait()
```

Which, when run, outputs:

```
➜ ./main.py 
hello from my shell
```

And here is an example that may be closer to your configuration:

```py
import subprocess

url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/var"
my_var = "hello"
subprocess.Popen(f"curl -s {url}/{my_var} | jq .var", shell=True).wait()
```

output:

```
➜ ./main.py
"hello"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding and I tried ```subprocess.Popen(f"curl -I --silent GET {url} | awk '/x-ms-copy-status/ {print}'", shell=True).wait()``` based on my requirement... but it showing ```awk: line 1: syntax error at or near in
(23) Failed writing body```
how to fix this?

Comment: My guess is that you meant to use the awk command `print` not reference a python variable `print`, so you would need to escape the braces in the f-string. `{{print}}`. So, you want `subprocess.Popen(f"curl -I --silent GET {url} | awk '/x-ms-copy-status/ {{print}}'", shell=True).wait()`